# How to build relational graph using elasticsearch data

Tags: elasticsearch, d3.js, graph, xpack

We are building log analytics applicaton in which we are using Graylog & Elasticsearch. Since I have installed Elasticsearch but somehow I want to take the data from elasticsearch and create relational  graphs with the data on my own instead of using Xpack-Graph.

i could have used xpack graph api and do http calls to get data but its not free ware and i'm not sure that we will be able to buy one licence

is there any other alternative for xpack graph api which is free ??

or can i query directly to elastic using aggregation if so how feasible it is?? can yo share me some resource on this

Kindly share your thoughts on this.

Comment: You can use `kibana` I guess.

Comment: @Richa
I want to build a relational graph from the elasticsearch data. If you take an example Graph API in X-Pack where its able to find the relation between the selected fields of the index pattern.
We are trying to build the same type of model instead of using X-Pack Graph API. I am not sure where kibana will give us relational graph.

Is there any other alternative way to approach this??

Let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: Tool/product/framework recommendation questions are off-topic for StackOverflow. As are licensing questions.